# user vs sudo vs sudo_user in ansible playbooks

Tags: sudo, ansible

I have read the Ansible documentation but I am still a bit confused about the three following parameters in ansible playbooks: user, sudo, sudo_user.

I have tried the following playbooks with different combination of the parameters:

1. user:deploy => Works
2. user:deploy and sudo: True => **Hangs on the git task**
3. user:deploy, sudo: True and sudo_user: deploy => Works

What does sudo_user actually do?
When and why should I use each of these combinations?

```
- hosts: all
  user: deploy
  sudo: True
  sudo_user: deploy

  tasks:
      - name: Ensure code directory
        file: dest=/home/deploy/code state=directory

      - name: Deploy app
        git: repo=git@bitbucket.org:YAmikep/djangotutorial.git dest=/home/deploy/code
```

Thanks

Answer (score 72):

- `user` is the user you're ssh'ing as. With your config, you're ssh'ing as `deploy`.
- `sudo_user` is the user you're sudo'ing on the host when `sudo: yes` is set.

So I think in your case none of `sudo` and `sudo_user` are necessary if you can ssh as `deploy`.

However, if you ssh as root, you need to set 
`sudo_user: deploy` and `sudo: yes`.

If you ask for 'sudo' but don't specify any user, Ansible will use the default set in your `~/.ansible.cfg` (`sudo_user`), and will default to `root`.

Note that `user` is deprecated (because it's confusing). You should use `remote_user` instead.

EDIT: Case #2 probably hangs because of ssh confirmation issues : you probably have bitbucket.org host key in `~deploy/.ssh/known_hosts` but **NOT** in `~root/.ssh/known_hosts`

UPDATE: As of Ansible 2.x, use `become` and `become_user` instead of the deprecated `sudo` and `sudo_user`. Example usage:

```
- hosts: all
  user: deploy
  become: true
  become_user: deploy

  tasks:
      - name: Ensure code directory
        file: dest=/home/deploy/code state=directory

      - name: Deploy app
        git: repo=git@bitbucket.org:YAmikep/djangotutorial.git dest=/home/deploy/cod
```

Comment: What happens if you have `sudo: yes` and `sudo_user: root` in a playbook that has a role, are the tasks in this role executed as root? If so: when a task in a role uses `remove_user`, will it switch to this user, or will it in this case ssh to the machine with this user?

Comment: @rednaw, did you try adding some 'whoami' statements to check which user is used where? what is your use case?

Comment: @rednaw : yes, as root (and you supposedly ssh'ed as another user). `remote_user` won't switch, since it's the user you're ssh'ing as.

Comment: `sudo` is now deprecated and replaced with `become` http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/become.html#for-those-from-pre-1-9-sudo-and-su-still-work